# How to read nnet results

Tags: r, neural-network

i have a quick question, how to read the wts results of the neural networks nnet. Does is go first layer, starting from the intercept, input 1 to hidden 1, input 1 to hidden 2.... than input 2 to all the nodes than continuing to hidden layer to output layer?

```
  nn$wts
      [1]  3050.8760936  3107.0191968 -3564.4774407  -727.7370641 -5428.0323370 -4404.2098978 -2064.8889704
      [8]  1456.2299660 -3243.1321916  2489.6174523   280.1332898 -1210.5267151   415.1520279   896.0419093
     [15]  -246.6938749  2337.0836060  1349.1387371   245.1213787  -678.4449843 -2301.9736401  1763.3316270
     [22] -2097.4340748 -2668.2344484
```

Comment: There can't be a second hidden layer. nnet fits single-hidden-layer neural networks

Comment: i have editted the question, hopefully someone knows the answer

Comment: An answer is given in a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/13856013/170792

Answer (score 2):

A quick way to figure out what is going on is to use

```
summary(nn)
```

This gives a nice table which summarizes which weights correspond to which nodes.